# ASP.NET Session State Sql Server mode

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session-state

My problem is regarding title written above. Currently I have some functions that rely on Sessions to do the job. Everything works smoothly when it is left to default. However, I do not like the idea of losing sessions in case of crash and I have modified my web.config to use Sql Server mode instead.

I have run the necessary commands to create tables and stored procedures in my database using aspnet_sql.exe

I am able to store values into the database but have not been successful retrieving them. Since it has been working fine with InProc mode, I think I can safely assume that there's nothing wrong with my codes.

Here's my web.config setting:

```
        <sessionState mode="SQLServer" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" cookieless="false" timeout="120" sqlCommandTimeout="30" compressionEnabled="true" 
                                sqlConnectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=mytest;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=mytest;Password=mytest;"/>
```

Your help is very much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: According to me it's not the aspnet_sql.exe tool but the aspnet_regsql.exe tool (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(v=VS.100).aspx)

Comment: Yea that's the tool. I wasn't too precise with the tool used. However, using that tool through command line, tables and stored procedures were created in my database.

Answer (score 4):

It's not safe to assume that your code is not at fault. One scenario that comes to mind is that the objects you are caching are not marked as [serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx). Ordinarily, this would throw an Exception, and you would be aware of it. However if you were also suppressing exceptions in a catch block, then you would seemingly be able to store values, but not retrieve them.

Why do you suddenly need to make all your objects serializable? Well, when you are using InProc, you're objects are stored in memory. However, when you use SQL, they need to be written (AKA serialized) to the database.

In code:

```
try {
    Session["MyKey"] = SomeNonSerializableObject
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ' Suppress all exceptions 
}
```

I would also confirm that your ASPState user (`mytest` in your example) has all the correct permissions they require. The easy way to test this is to make them a db_owner on the ASPState database **AND** the temp database. If this fixes the problem, then you know that it's a DB permissions issue.

Why the tempdb I hear you ask? Well, by default, the session state tables will be created in the tempdb.

Comment: My intention is not to make my objects serializable. I just want Sessions to be more persistent. The project will be hosted on a shared environment. Anything happens to IIS, my sessions will be gone. I have not added any try / catch blocks to retrieve sessions. By using the aspnet_regsql.exe tool, I created session state tables and stored proc in my DB (custom) which is why I allowCustomSqlDatabase in my web.config

Comment: You have to make your objects serializable in order to get them stored in the database. That's just How It Works.

Comment: Yes, I did mark my classes as Serializable by including the attribute. However, it's to no avail.

Comment: You say "I have not added any try / catch blocks to retrieve sessions". However, my code illustrates the problem is a try / catch when you are setting the session. Can you confirm you are not suppressing exceptions when **setting** the session?